# How to resolve an encryption issue?

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, encryption, android-10

I used a lockscreen to encrypt my phone and accidentally messed up the system and TWRP. I've since formatted it and am using it normally, albeit without root this time lol. But, just in case, I made a backup of the data beforehand. Is it possible to decrypt it if I remember the lockscreen? I can't get encryption keys from the phone because I've already formatted it to a new system, but can I get them from another software that can read the files? I read about it online, and apparently there are a bunch of strange commands you need to type into the system, and I'm not too familiar with this because I don't want to mess anything up, and it's really quite complicated stuff to understand. What I gathered from this was that you would have to format the phone again in order to recover the filesystem data, which I obviously cannot do. So please don't just recommend esoteric guides to me as if I'll magically understand everything; that's why I'm asking in the first place. So, is there a solution here that a *layperson* can understand? Can I somehow decrypt the image using only a PC, inputting the password through some special tool or something? Or is there some other way?

Comment: no way. once encryption key is gone no software in the world can read the files. that's the purpose of encryption. independent using password or not, the key is lost forever

Comment: @alecxs But I know the password in any case, so it is possible to maybe recover from the image?

Comment: the password is worthless without the encryption key (which is random generated)

Comment: @alecxs Is there something I can do if I backed up the whole storage beforehand? Is the encryption key stored there?

Comment: @alecxs Well it was on Android 10, a full backup of `mmcblk0p66`, can this be recovered some way?

Comment: depends on encryption type. for FDE it is possible only if crypto footer is present at end of mmcblk0p66. for FBE it is possible only if TEE keystore is not flushed (should not happen on formatting)

Comment: @alecxs I believe it's FDE, actually. What can I do, then?

Comment: `adb push mmcblk0p66 /dev/block/mmcblk0p66` and reboot

Comment: @alecxs Is it just going to work like that? Like, no extra step?

Comment: there is no extra step. either crypto footer is last 16384 bytes of mmcblk0p66 then it will restored and TWRP is able to decrypt. or crypto footer is located other partition (which you don't have backup) and therefore unable to decrypt